# Interval Won't clear/ clientX &/or clientY not working

Tags: javascript

I am making a simple drawing program using dat.gui

I have a function that runs every 50 milliseconds using a set interval like so:

```
window.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    let run = setInterval(function() {
        // function here
    }, 50)
})
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    clearInterval(run)
})
```

So What's the problem with that? I am also having troubles with clientX and clientY.

What I have is this:

```
window.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    let run = setInterval(function(event) {
        let x = event.clientX,
          y = event.clientY;
    }, 50)
})
```

I have tried using it without event as a parameter, and it still doesn't work. The odd thing is that it works in an instance like this:

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
    let x = event.clientX,
      y = event.clientY;
}
```

So am I missing something? I have tried looking this up and haven't found anything. I also have the full thing here:

http://codepen.io/TheAndersMan/pen/pNZwrN?editors=0011

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: variable scope...

Comment: @nnnnnn what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean that the `run` variable isn't in scope in the second place you try to use it: it's declared as a local variable in the other function.

Comment: @nnnnnn Ahhh, I see what you mean thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    let run = setInterval(function() {
        // function here
    }, 50)
})
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    clearInterval(run)
})
```

You cannot use `run` variable inside `mouseup` listener, because they was defined in other scope.

You can pass `event` variable into interval:

```
setInterval(function(){}, 50, event);
```

Comment: Good point about passing variables to `setInterval`. That cleans stuff up quite a bit.

Comment: So would event in the setInterval replace the parameter?

Comment: @TheAndersMan yes

Comment: thank you, I realized this problem just recently, but the coordinates don't change as you move your mouse, until you lift up. How would you make the coordinates change as you move your mouse?

Comment: @TheAndersMan i've updated the demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xRaOBz?editors=0011 one of the possible solution is store last mousemoving coordinates

Comment: Thanks! That is crazy how little you changed.

Answer (score 1):

In your callback function, you're missing the passed parameter `event` (the event object), and your `run` variable should also be declared outside the scope of either listener.

**Edit:** In order to track the position of the mouse, you need to attach an event listener to the `mousemove` event, so I had to add another function to serve as this event handler, which is attached on `mousedown` and detached on `mouseup`.

```js
let run,
    x, y

window.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
    run = setInterval(function() {
        console.log(x, y)
    }, 50)
    trackMouse(event)
    this.addEventListener('mousemove', trackMouse)
})

window.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
    clearInterval(run)
    this.removeEventListener('mousemove', trackMouse)
})

function trackMouse (event) {
    x = event.clientX
    y = event.clientY
}
```

Comment: That is not is the problem. In that instance without the parameter it works just fine. It doesn't work inside mousedown.

Comment: Without the parameter, it only works because a legacy `window.event` object exists; that's not the recommended way to do it. I updated my answer to show you how to scope `run` as well.

Comment: ok, so I didn't realize that this was even a problem until you fixed another. I didn't ask this but is there a way to be getting the client X and Y constantly on mouse down? What I mean is that on mouse down you can move it around it will give you the same coordinates until you lift up.

Comment: Is there a simple way to male them change?